# Play Framework: Composing multiple ActionTransformers - can I add fields in multiple transformers and access them all in the invokeBlock?

Tags: scala, playframework, composition

Using Play action composition, I'm wondering if there's a way to add fields to a request in multiple `ActionTransformer`s, such that I can access both fields in the request.

Simple example that doesn't work:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, ActionTransformer, Request, Results, WrappedRequest}

class RequestWithName[A](request: Request[A], val name: String) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
def addName(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionTransformer[Request, RequestWithName] {
  override def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ec
  override def transform[A](request: Request[A]): Future[RequestWithName[A]] = ???
}

class RequestWithUserId[A](request: Request[A], val userId: String) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
def addUserId(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionTransformer[Request, RequestWithUserId] {
  override def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ec
  override def transform[A](request: Request[A]): Future[RequestWithUserId[A]] = ???
}

Action.andThen(addName).andThen(addUserId) { req =>
  Results.Ok(req.name + req.userId) // compile error: name not available
}

Action.andThen(addUserId).andThen(addName) { req =>
  Results.Ok(req.name + req.userId) // compile error: userId not available
}
```

It makes sense why these compile errors happen - the last `andThen` returns an `ActionTransformer` that has only one of the two fields. But is there a way to accomplish the same thing, without making them aware of each other? Eg. I could add a `RequestWithUserIdAndName` - but then I can't compose that with other transforms that add even more fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about writing something like `EnrichedRequest` which has a collection of enrichments (implemented as some sealed hierarchy), so that you would lift it first, and then add enrichments as you see fit?

```
sealed trait Enrichment
case class UserName(name: String) extends Enrichment
case class UserId(name: String) extends Enrichment

class EnrichedRequest[A](
  request: Request[A],
  val enrichments: List[Enrichment]
) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
def asEnriched(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionTransformer[Request, EnrichedRequest] {
  ...
}

def addName(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionTransformer[EnrichedRequest, EnrichedRequest] {
  ...
}

def addUserId(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionTransformer[EnrichedRequest, EnrichedRequest] {
  ...
}

Action.andThen(asEnriched).andThen(addName).andThen(addUserId) { ... }
Action.andThen(asEnriched).andThen(addUserId).andThen(addName) { ... }
```

That would be easy to implement and freely extensible. The only downside is that to extract data you would have to do something like:

```
enrichments.collect {
  case UserName(name) => name
}.head
```

to extract data back.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach, thanks. Another answer I got elsewhere was https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Highlights26#Request-attributes - Play has something similar built in that I'd missed. It basically has the same issue that there's no compile-time knowledge of exactly which enrichments there are. It seems like the type system doesn't really support this unfortunately. I'll accept this answer, thanks!